# onPause: count increases by 2

Tags: java, android, database, onpause

I have a score system that counts how much question I answered in my quiz app. In `onPause()`, I write the count of played questions in database.

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SpielDBOpenHandler sdb = new SpielDBOpenHandler(Allgemeinwissen.this);
    sdb.insert(3, fragencount, 3, 4);
}
```

That works fine.

I raise the score in an `onClick` method of a button:

```
fragencount += 1;
```

Now, when I close the app via home button and reopen it and press back, it counts two times. When I totally close my app and open a new task of the app, it counts normally. What can I do?

**EDIT:**

The button listener looks like this:

```
ausw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAuswertung);
        ausw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  fragencount += 1
                      ...
            }
```

**EDIT2:**

Ok I know know that onPause() isCalled when I press the home button to temporarily close the app and again when I am in the app again and press the back button. Is there a way that `onPause()` isn´t called when I temporarily close the app via home button?

Comment: " it counts two times" what does it means ? every time you click the counter is increased by 2 ?

Comment: Yeah, it increases by 2.

Comment: can you edit your question and post little more code ? (onCreate, onResume, how do you add the listener, ...)